# How to execute jQuery after page refresh

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress and Woocommerce, currently I have a mini cart in my header so when the user clicks the icon it shows the contents of their cart (without leaving the page).

The jQuery currently has the opacity set to `0` as soon as the document is ready. I would like to know how I can can have that mini cart open when the add to cart button is clicked?  Because the page refreshes when the add to cart button is clicked I don't know how I can change the opacity of the below to `1` only after that add to cart refresh is triggered.

Here is the jQuery and I left my attempt commented out.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#nw-cart-drop-content').css('opacity',0).addClass('nw-hidden');
    $('#nw-cart-drop-toggle').click(function(e) {
        if($('#nw-cart-drop-content').hasClass('nw-hidden')) {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
        }else {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:0},500);
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').addClass('nw-hidden');
        }
    });

    /*$('button.lato').click(function(e) {

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
            });

    });*/

});
```

Comment: Is there any indication in the URL that the add to cart action was fired? Otherwise you could have a custom selector that checks for whatever content is unique to the new page after that action and if found unhide the cart

Comment: @Anthony has the right idea, which is that you will need a 'persistent' variable/flag/indicator available after refresh... I would suggest a cookie if it's not available in the URL.

Comment: @Anthony, yes whenever a user adds something to cart then this is appended after the url: /?added-to-cart=13644 - Where the number (13644) will of course change depending on what product is added.  So in its entirety it looks similar to this: http://my-website.com/shop-my-product/product/?added-to-cart=13644

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,  Am not tested the code yet!!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#nw-cart-drop-content').css('opacity',0).addClass('nw-hidden');
    $('#nw-cart-drop-toggle').click(function(e) {
        SetCookie('CartAdded','yes',1);
        OpenCart();
    });  
       var isCartAdded = ReadCookie('CartAdded');
       if(CartAdded=='yes'){
           /// use the opacity code here 
       }

 });

     function OpenCart(){
           if($('#nw-cart-drop-content').hasClass('nw-hidden')) {
              $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
         }else {
             $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:0},500);
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').addClass('nw-hidden');
         }  
     }

    function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
             var today = new Date();
             var expire = new Date();
            if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
             expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
             document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
      }

      function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
             var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
             var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
             if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
             if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
             var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
             if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
          return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
        }
```

Comment: This doesnt work because this shows the menu widget all the time, I only need the opacity to change to 1 once the user clicks the add to cart button (button.lato).  My problem is setting the opacity to 1 after the page refreshes.  Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button.lato').click(function(e) {
    $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
});
```

I think the click handler would be executed before refresh. So the above snippet should work.

Comment: The DOM will reset after the page refresh/submit and opacity style/css lost

Comment: This was my initial approach but just like @funcbigO says, the opacity style is lost once the page refreshes and it reverts back to opacity:0

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated in your comments the presence of a URL parameter, you can check for the parameter in your function.  Just replace the hard coded url (http://mysite.com/?added-to-cart=13644) in the following sample with 'window.location' and now the cart will show after the page is submitted as long as the querystring is pereserved, which indicated it was.

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/X664G/7/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //alert(getParameter('http://mysite.com/?added-to-cart=13644','added-to-cart'));
    if (getParameter('http://mysite.com/?added-to-cart=13644','added-to-cart'))
       $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
    else {
         $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:0},500);
         $('#nw-cart-drop-content').addClass('nw-hidden');
    }
    $('#nw-cart-drop-toggle').click(function(e) {
        if($('#nw-cart-drop-content').hasClass('nw-hidden')) {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
        }else {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:0},500);
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').addClass('nw-hidden');
        }
    });
});
function getParameter(url,param){
    url = url.split('?');
    var pattern = new RegExp(param+'=(.*?)(;|&|$)','gi');
    return url[1].split(pattern)[1];
}
```

Comment: I see your logic and it makes sense but for some reason it does not work.  Its like there is something wrong with the function or the if/else because when the page first loads or after add to cart button is clicked the mini cart is still showing opacity:1.

What you have here should check the url for a ? and then change mini cart to opacity:1, right?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on funcbigO's method I came up with this and it seems to work fine.  Thanks for all the help, hopefully this helps someone else browsing.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?added-to-cart=") > 0) {
       $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
    } else {
        $('#nw-cart-drop-content').css('opacity',0).addClass('nw-hidden');
    }

    $('#nw-cart-drop-toggle').click(function(e) {
        if($('#nw-cart-drop-content').hasClass('nw-hidden')) {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:1},500).removeClass('nw-hidden');
        }else {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').animate({opacity:0},500);
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content').addClass('nw-hidden');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `added_to_cart` event provide by woocommerce to trigger custom JS.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function () {
        if ($('#nw-cart-drop-content').hasClass('nw-hidden')) {
            $('#nw-cart-drop-content')
                .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500)
                .removeClass('nw-hidden');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```